# SOAP request from within an AutoLISP/AutoCAD macro

Tags: soap, lisp, autocad, autolisp

We have built a webservice for a client that uses AutoCAD. They have a macro that runs in AutoCAD that builds a SOAP request. But they have not figured out how to actually **send()** the soap request to us.

So the XML is all proper and ready to go, they just need to send it.

Anybody out there familiar enough with AutoLISP to know how to send a SOAP request?

Do they have to use an external COM component or does AutoLISP have native SOAP objects/methods?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To my knowledge AutoLISP does not have any native SOAP stuff.  It does however have a fairly complete COM interface.  You should be able to connect to any COM module that does whatever SOAP methods that you need.

Comment: Yep, agreed. After doing some digging, we just decided to use an external program/object to do the soap call. We are just using the AutoLISP to kick out the XML Parameter that is required. Then that is passed to the external program. Thanks!